# Complex intengration giving wrong answer

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2x^2 + ax +a^2}$$

I am getting the wrong answer, namely, $\frac{2\pi}{a\sqrt{7}}$:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2x^2 + ax +a^2} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2(x^2 + a/2x +a^2/2)}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{2(x-(\frac{-i}{4} (-i a + \sqrt7 a)))(x-(\frac{i}{4} (i a + \sqrt7 a)))}
\end{align*}

Closed it by above:
$$=\frac{2\pi i}{2(\frac{i}{4} (i a + \sqrt7 a)-(\frac{-i}{4} (-i a + \sqrt7 a))} = \frac{2\pi i}{2(\frac{i}{4} ( \sqrt7 a)+(\frac{i}{4} ( \sqrt7 a))} = \frac{2\pi }{( \sqrt7 a)}$$

Could you point me where is my error?

Comment: What are you assuming about $a$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OPs, i forgot it. The question says a>0

Comment: What does "closed it by above" mean? You skip a vast number of steps so no one can tell where exactly you made an error.

Comment: Why do you think your answer is incorrect?

Comment: @Bonnaduck Because the given answer by the authority was different than mine. In fact, his answer was two times mine

Comment: @AmejiB. I can't see the vast number of step. Since the integral diverges for r tends to infinity, just close it around a semicircle from 0 to pi, isn' is right?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28-infty+to+infty%291%2F%7B2x%5E2%2Bax%2Ba%5E2%7D+dx%2C+a%3E0, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kcsiidi9xt

Comment: "his answer was two times mine" - maybe they forgot the denominator isn't monic.

Comment: I also got $\dfrac{2\pi}{a\sqrt7}$.

Comment: I don't think you have to use complex numbers to get the value. In fact, you just need $$ \int\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac1a\arctan(\frac xa)+c. $$